# docker-compose debugging service show `pwd` and `ls -l` at run?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file with a service called 'app'. When I try to run my docker file I don't see the service with `docker ps` but I do with `docker ps -a`.

I looked at the logs:

```
docker logs my_app_1
python: can't open file '//apps/index.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

In order to debug I wanted to be able to see the home directory and the files and dirs contained there when the app attempts to run.

Is there a command I can add to docker-compose that would show me the `pwd` and `ls -l` of the container when it attempts to run `index.py`?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "apps/index.py"]
```

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8050:8050
```

My directory structure:

```
my_app:
      * docker-compose.yaml
      * app
        * Dockerfile
        * apps
          * index.py
```

Comment: You can add `RUN pwd && ls -l` to your Dockerfile

Comment: If you create an interactive shell in the Python process's namespaces, you can run those commands yourself. See `nsenter`.

Comment: You can inspect the value of the working directory in your failed image with `docker inspect <container-name> --format='{{.Config.WorkingDir}}'`. If you already recycled the container, you can get the same info from the image. Simply replace the container name with `image:tag` in the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a RUN statement in the application Dockerfile to run these commands.
Example:

```
FROM python:3
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Run your commands
RUN pwd && ls -l

CMD ["python", "apps/index.py"]
```

Then you chan check the logs of the build process and view the results.
I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: It would actually be better to do it on one line only, so that it doesn't add to many layers to the image

Comment: Is there any way to echo the `RUN` output into the docker terminal output?

Comment: which logs are you referring to?

Answer (score -1):

If you're just trying to debug an image you've already built, you can [docker-compose run](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) an alternate command:

```sh
docker-compose run apps \
  ls -l ./apps
```

You don't need to modify anything in your Dockerfile to be able to do this (assuming it uses `CMD` correctly; see below).

If you need to do more intensive debugging, you can `docker-compose run apps sh` (or, if your image has it, `bash`) to get an interactive shell.  The container will include any mounted volumes and be on the same Docker network as the named container, but won't have published ports.

Note that the command here replaces the `CMD` in the Dockerfile.  If your image uses `ENTRYPOINT` for its main command, or if it has a complete command split between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` (especially, if you have `ENTRYPOINT ["python"]`), these need to be combined into a single `CMD` for this to work.  If your `ENTRYPOINT` is a wrapper script that does some first-time setup and then runs the `CMD`, this approach will work fine; the debugging `ls` or `sh` will run after the first-time setup happens.